# how to prevent chrome follow any location headers

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension

What plugin or settings to use in google chrome to prevent follow by any `location` header? Can't find any information about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found extension for Chrome - "Tamper chrome". It allows to edit response headers.